# Not receiving any response from server after payment success - Authorize.Net yii2

Tags: php, yii2, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I want to use `Authorize.Net` for payment but got stuck in middle.
There is not any Error message,
I am using SANDBOX for `authCaptureTransaction`,
First I have created token with amount , return url.

```
    $response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse(\net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::SANDBOX);
```

after generating token, I add it into form and post to 
`http://test.authorize.net/payment/payment`

it redirects to payment, but after success/cancel it returns to url with empty response.
Please refer my below code.

```
    //function for generating coupon
    function getAnAcceptPaymentPage($amount)
    {
    /* Create a merchantAuthenticationType object with authentication details
    retrieved from the constants file */
    $merchantAuthentication = new \net\authorize\api\contract\v1\MerchantAuthenticationType();
    $merchantAuthentication->setName(Yii::$app->params['authLoginName']);
    $merchantAuthentication->setTransactionKey(Yii::$app->params['authTransId']);

    // Set the transaction's refId
    $refId = 'ref' . time();
    //create a transaction
    $transactionRequestType = new \net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionRequestType();//AnetAPI\TransactionRequestType();
    $transactionRequestType->setTransactionType("authCaptureTransaction");
    $transactionRequestType->setAmount($amount);

    // Set Hosted Form options
    $setting1 = new \net\authorize\api\contract\v1\SettingType();//AnetAPI\SettingType();
    $setting1->setSettingName("hostedPaymentButtonOptions");
    $setting1->setSettingValue("{\"text\": \"Pay\"}");

    $setting2 = new \net\authorize\api\contract\v1\SettingType();//AnetAPI\SettingType();
    $setting2->setSettingName("hostedPaymentOrderOptions");
    $setting2->setSettingValue("{\"show\": true}");
    $setting3 = new \net\authorize\api\contract\v1\SettingType();//AnetAPI\SettingType();
    $setting3->setSettingName("hostedPaymentReturnOptions");
    $returnUrlSuccess = helpers\Url::to('site/receipt', TRUE);
    $returnUrlCancel = helpers\Url::to('site/cancel', TRUE);
    $setting3->setSettingValue("{\"url\": \"".$returnUrlSuccess."\", \"cancelUrl\": \"".$returnUrlCancel."\", \"showReceipt\": true}");
    // Build transaction request
    $request = new \net\authorize\api\contract\v1\GetHostedPaymentPageRequest();//AnetAPI\Get        HostedPaymentPageRequest();
    $request->setMerchantAuthentication($merchantAuthentication);
    $request->setRefId($refId);
    $request->setTransactionRequest($transactionRequestType);
    $request->addToHostedPaymentSettings($setting1);
    $request->addToHostedPaymentSettings($setting2);
    $request->addToHostedPaymentSettings($setting3);

    //execute request
    $controller = new \net\authorize\api\controller\GetHostedPaymentPageController($request);//AnetController\GetHostedPaymentPageController($request);
    $response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse(\net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::SANDBOX);


    if (($response != null) && ($response->getMessages()->getResultCode() == "Ok")) {
    echo $response->getToken();
    } else {
    echo "ERROR : Failed to get hosted payment page token\n";
    $errorMessages = $response->getMessages()->getMessage();
    echo "RESPONSE : " . $errorMessages[0]->getCode() . " " .$errorMessages[0]->getText() . "\n";die;
    }
    return $response;
    }

    //main function
    public function actionPayment()
    {
    $token = $this->getAnAcceptPaymentPage($pack->package_cost);

    $token = $token->getToken(); //Generating token successfully

    return $this->render('/package/payform', [
    'pack' => $pack, 'token' =>$token, 'userDetails' => $user, 'url'=>$url,
    ]);
    }

    //form where i put token
    //payform.php
    {
    <form target="payframe" id="send_hptoken" action="http://test.authorize.net/payment/payment" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token;?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Get Accept Hosted page"/>
    </form>
    }


    //return success function
    public function actionReceipt()
    {
    //receiving email of payment received but no response here
    //empty response;
    //tried $_POST, $_GET, $_REQUEST
    print_r($_POST);
    die;
    }

    //return cancel function
    public function actionCancel()
    {
    //empty response;
    //tried $_POST, $_GET, $_REQUEST
    print_r($_POST);
    die;
    }
```

Please let me know what am I missing here.